# Filter Data Frame by dates in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dataframe

I have a dataframe `query2`:

```
    Site   TripDate       Volume
0   003l 1990-06-10  2202.571850
1   003l 1991-07-26  2543.566201
2   003l 1991-11-01  1702.228651
3   003l 1992-10-15  2753.163510
4   003l 1993-04-01  2550.538237
5   003l 1993-10-08  2241.329021
```

And another `table1`:

```
     TripDate  Count
0  1990-06-10     35
1  1991-07-26     35
2  1992-10-15     34
3  1993-10-08     35
```

I need to filter `query2` to only include `TripDates` in `table1`.  The resulting filtered table would look like:

```
    Site   TripDate       Volume
0   003l 1990-06-10  2202.571850
1   003l 1991-07-26  2543.566201
2   003l 1992-10-15  2753.163510
3   003l 1993-10-08  2241.329021
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging):

```
In [11]: t1.merge(q2)
Out[11]:
     TripDate  Count  Site       Volume
0  1990-06-10     35  003l  2202.571850
1  1991-07-26     35  003l  2543.566201
2  1992-10-15     34  003l  2753.163510
3  1993-10-08     35  003l  2241.329021
```

By default this merges on shared columns (in this case only TripDate, but you can specify):

```
In [12]: t1.merge(q2, on="TripDate")
Out[12]:
     TripDate  Count  Site       Volume
0  1990-06-10     35  003l  2202.571850
1  1991-07-26     35  003l  2543.566201
2  1992-10-15     34  003l  2753.163510
3  1993-10-08     35  003l  2241.329021
```